# PHP Warning: Undefined array key 0 in

Tags: php

I am getting the PHP Warning 'Undefined array key 0 in' on the following piece of code:

```
if ($reports[0]->rank == null) {
    $output['result']['rank'] = 0; // no reports found
} else {
    $output['result']['rank'] = $reports[0]->rank; // reports found, return lowest rank (highest warning level)
}
```

It is custom code I had written for a custom wordpress plugin a few years ago and unfortunately the web development company I used is no longer in business so I can't go back to them. I'm really stuck and wondering if anyone could give me any tips as to how I could fix this. I note the site is running PHP 8 in case this is relevant.

Thanks

Comment: it seems your report array is empty. Maybe do you have more relevant code to diagnose why it is empty ?

Comment: add a `echo '<pre>' . print_r($reports,1) . '</pre>';` just before the IF and see whats in that array, or if its an array

Answer (score 0):

the `$reports` is an empty array, that's why it can't find the first element.

Comment: This should be a comment